# Can someone travelling close to the speed of light witness the end of the universe?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, speed-of-light, time-dilation

I have read that objects with non-zero rest mass cannot attain light speed $c$. But for the sake of this question let us assume that Mr. X can get as close to $c$ as he wants. So this means that an observer watching on from Earth see his time pass by normally whereas time slows down for X. No matter how many billions of years pass by in Earth only a few milliseconds pass by for X (obviously he doesn't realize anything).

Now consider that Mr. X never encounters any obstacles in his path to stop him. Will he reach the end of the universe - almost instantaneously in his own experience - both from the perspectives of time and space?

Note: I am imagining if the end of the universe was to occur it would somehow reduce X's speed significantly so that he will start to experience what is going on around him again.

-------------+++-----------------

EDIT : I am not altering the original question because some of the comments indicate that a few of our friends have understood what I actually meant.

To clarify, this article explains some of the possible theories for end of the universe 
 https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_fate_of_the_universe

Back to the questions,

1. Will Mr. X witness any of these events?
2. If the Universe has no end will he reach the edge of the universe (assuming it is finite)?

Please consider that Mr. X has a technology that will accelerate him close to $c$ and we need not bother about how he did it.

Comment: Interesting question :) Are you sure that the speed of light cancels out time for the object traveling with it? Remember, light itself requires time in order to get from point A to point B

Comment: @AlexDoe yes, because to him lenghts are contracted (assuming speed close to c here, as c cannot be reached)

Comment: I do not think this should be put on hold, the question is mainstream if you assume a speed close to c.

Comment: @Wolphram Sure, but how close to c? The gamma required to survive until all black holes have evaporated  (to pick an arbitrary end of the universe epoch) is enormous. How many galaxies worth of energy would that take...

Comment: @PM2Ring good point, have you made a calculation to know how much energy would he need to advance, let us say, 20 billion years until the hipothetical big rip?

Comment: This is certainly mainstream physics. Suppose Mr. X accelerates at constant acceleration. The answer is yes he will reach the edge of the observable universe (14 billion light years away). According to this book: https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642372759 if he accelerates at g, he can reach the edge of the universe and back in 50 years. In the earth frame, this will take 28 billion years. In his frame, the universe length-contracts to the order of 10-100 light-years. (Of course in real life he would be fried by the CMB.)

Comment: @WolphramJonny Please explain what contracting  lengths have to do with contracting time

Comment: @AlexDoe that to the traveller it makes sense to reach far away distances in a short time because the distances have been shortened to him, so it does not matter how long it takes for light to travel from A to B (to a stationary observer relative to A and B)

Comment: @Wolphram No, I haven't. But 20 billion years is nothing compared to the timescales mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_of_an_expanding_universe). In my previous comment I was thinking along the lines of $10^{50`$ or $10^{100}$ years.

Comment: If someone wants to do fuel calculations, there are formulae on the classic Usenet [relativistic rocket](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/Rocket/rocket.html) page. Note that merely going to Andromeda (2Gly) with constant 1g acceleration (without stopping) takes 4100 tonnes of energy per 1kg of payload, (i.e., 2050 tonnes of antimatter annihilating with 2050 tonnes of matter in a perfect engine).

Comment: Oops! That should be 2Mly, 2 million lightyears to Andromeda. Sorry about that.

Comment: @PM2Ring yes, it looks like energy could be a limiting factor

Comment: What does "the end of the universe" mean? Current cosmological models don't have anything like a Big Crunch.

Comment: Depends a great deal on two unknowns : (1) Is there an actual end for the universe or does it just never end ? and (2) Do protons decay ?  Also the observer will not be able to see the entire universe (or what's left of it) because his observational horizon is limited by the speed of light, but the expansion of the universe is not limited by this - see [Cosmological Horizon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_horizon).

Comment: Hi everyone, i know that as per our current understanding of physics it is almost impossible to attain speeds close to c. But can we ignore that part and assume it is possible just for the sake of this question? Because what would happen after that is what fascinates me more  :)

Comment: @BenCrowell if a Big Crunch or a similar event does not end the universe for all eternity does Mr. X reach it's edge one day? my thinking is that he does not because of the expansion of spacetime. But we have to consider that he is on an eternal journey.

Comment: @deadpool The universe doesn't have an edge. Either it's infinite in spatial extent, or it has positive curvature & wraps back on itself, like the surface of a sphere. The Wikipedia article linked in my 2nd comment discusses various scenarios of the far future.

Comment: @PM 2Ring  so will he witness The Big Freeze mentioned in that article?

Comment: @deadpool He could, given enough energy. But that's extremely unlikely. I haven't done the calculations, but my guess is that there isn't enough energy in the entire observable universe. Also, at very high speed, the friction from the interstellar medium becomes huge, and the CMB gets blueshifted to deadly gamma radiation.